# Почему VK API возвращает пустое "photo":"[]"?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я уже все способы попробовал, которые гугл выдавал, но так и не пойму, что не так сделал.
Подскажите. Заранее спасибо!

`$_GET['url']` хранит результат `photos.getWallUploadServer`.

```
<?php 
      if (!isset($_GET['url']))
        exit();

      $url = $_GET['url'];

      $img_src = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];
      $img_str = curl_file_create($img_src);

      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

      $data_str = array(
        'photo' => $img_str //'file1' => $img_str
      );

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_str);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));

      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      echo $result;
    ?>
```